# Trying to find the source of this image of Wonder Woman, ensnared amid flames, with a face hovering over her

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, wonder-woman

Trying to find which comic this scan came from. Tried looking into retroactive series and *DC Comics Presents: Wonder Woman Adventures*, but couldn't find it.

[image: Wonder Woman struggles with a cable or tentacles grabbing her limbs and waist. A head with greenish skin and purple hair hovers above.]

Comment: Can you post a link to the web page where you found this image?

Comment: https://in.pinterest.com/pin/717479784388406684/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That panel is from a page in *[Wonder Woman Vol 2 #87](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_2_87)*. The character ensnaring Wonder Woman there is a guy called [Plasma](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Plasma_(New_Earth)).

[image: Page six from Wonder Woman Vol 2 #87, showing the panel where Wonder Woman is ensanred by the villain, Plasma.]

Comment: Nice! How'd you find it?

Comment: @fez - Process of elimination combined with some educated guesswork. I guessed the approximate time period the issue was likely to be from by the art style and the quality of the colouring; this told me it probably wasn't Pre-Crisis. I also knew the art wasn't by big name Post-Crisis artists like George Perez or John Byrne, so I was able to rule out those runs entirely. I then focused my search between the Perez and Byrne runs, until I found issues with an art style resembling the one shown in the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it.